# angularjs make long calendar

Tags: angularjs, calendar, long-integer

I am developing a calendar in angularjs, this calendar is composed by days, rooms and rateplans.
Example:

```
room/rateplan    | 2015-01-15 | 2015-01-16 | 2015-01-17 | 2015-01-18 | 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Simple Room      |     5      |      6     |      6     |      6     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   Room only     |    50€     |    55€     |    50€     |    50€     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   All inclusive |    65€     |    65€     |    65€     |    65€     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Doble Room       |     5      |      3     |      0     |      6     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   Room only     |    65€     |    65€     |    50€     |    65€     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   All inclusive |    50€     |    50€     |    50€     |    50€     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Using the calendar, the user can update the price in rateplans and the number of free rooms in rooms. This is working perfectly.

My problem is when a user select a lot of rooms and rateplans, angularjs takes a long time to render all calendar and the browser crashes.

My last solution is make the calendar with php but then I can't use angularjs.

Any solution?

In this link you can see and example of my calendar and how is generated:
http://jsfiddle.net/joucogi/rhhvnjsu

To generate the calendar, I have to, for each room, loop through all rateplans, and for each rateplan, loop through all days. There are a lot of loops and I think this is the cause of my problem when the user select a lot of rooms , rateplans and days.

Any idea or solution?

Comment: You should probably add more information, regarding which components you are using and, maybe, a code snippet showing the general structure of the problem. That will raise the likelihood of a useful answer. Your problem looks potentially interesting. Please, elaborate.

Comment: Can you provide some code via plunker or jsfiddle? The problem surely is not with angular if you haven't got large quantities of data. And when I say large, I mean thousands of records.

Comment: I am not in my office now, tomorrow I will add more information and I will provide some code.  Thanks for responding so quickly.

Comment: I have edited my problem and I have added more information and provided a link to jsfiddle with an example.

Answer (score 0):

At the end,  I made calendar with php and I used jquery for the events.
I couldn't solved the problem with angularjs or backbonejs.